# Dfference between strongly prime and prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

An ideal $P\subset R$ is *strongly prime*, if for any $x$ and $y$ in the quotient field of $R$, $xy\in P$ implies $x\in P$ or $y\in P$.

What is the difference between strongly prime ideal of $R$ and a prime ideal of $R$?

It seems that they are same .Thank you for your helping ..

Comment: What’s a strongly prime ideal? I googled and found [this paper](http://www.ijmsi.ir/files/site1/user_files_529145/admin-A-10-1-76-da20eec.pdf) where the definition is: An ideal $P ⊂ R$ is strongly prime, if for any $x$ and $y$ in the quotient field of $R$, $xy ∈ P$ implies $x ∈ P$ or $y ∈ P$. (So these are only defined for integral domains, I assume.) Is that your definition, too?

Comment: yes, this is definition of strongly prime ideal .

Comment: they are not the same i think: regard $(2)$ as an ideal of ${Z}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ and $3$, for an example of prime but not strongly prime

Comment: It seems to me $\mathbb Z$ has no strongly prime ideals.

Comment: @user104847 Looks like R being an integral domain was implicitly implied?

Answer (score 0):

As should be abundantly clear from the comments yesterday, they are far from similar. Jorst pointed out that $\frac23\cdot 3\in (2)\subseteq\Bbb Z$, and yet neither one of $\frac23$ or $3$ lies in $(2)$. I'll answer talking about a domain $R$ with field of quotients $Q$.

As for your question "what is the difference?" the first thing to point out is that the definitions *quantify over different sets*. "For all $x,y\in R$" is a wholly different statement from "For all $x,y\in Q$".

By adapting the argument above, you can show that no nonzero ideal of $\Bbb Z$ is strongly prime. For any $(p)$ with $p$ a nonzero prime, you can just take a prime $q$ other than $p$ and note $q\cdot frac{p}{q}\in (p)$, but $\frac{p}{q}, q\notin (p)$. The zero ideal, however, is always strongly prime.

What *can* be said? Of course, any strongly prime ideal not equal to $R$ is also a(n ordinary) prime ideal. I'm not sure how many sources include/exclude $R$ from this definition you gave.

Secondly, if $R$ is allowed into the definition above, then if $R$ is strongly prime, then the ideals of $R$ are linearly ordered. (This happens because $xx^{-1}=1\in R$ implies $x$ or $x^{-1}$ is in $R$, and this is a way to define a valuation domain.)